# Database design for unknown fields

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, entity-relationship

I am trying to make form builder in android. I have a real problem at designing database. In this application User first drags the required fields to the screen and change the labels of fields. The fields Contains:

1. CheckBox
2. RadioButton
3. TeXtBox
4. PlainText

This is my mockup:
[image: This is my first mockup]

[image: And form builder Activity]

I have real problem in designing database.I need a help to accomplish it.

Any Links to the tutorials or ER Diagrams will be really appreciated.
In this application user will drag his required fields to the screen as shown in mock up. Suppose when user drags on checkbox icon then the Editable Checkbox label and editable options will appear in the screen. Then Form builder names the label according to his requirements and options also. In this way he first builds the form .

Comment: Question isn't clear, add more detail...

Comment: I hope i made it clear.

Comment: You may take a look @ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: So, I guess you're trying to let your user design their own DB table schema, with a GUI tool(your APP) ?

Comment: Yes, i appreciate you but i need idea how to handle to these schema.

Answer (score 1):

That's what I created in 10 minutes, hope it helps.

- TB_FieldType //field type

UUID_Type,

Type_Name, (Checkbox, RadioButton, Textbox, PlainText, Password, DropdownSelect...)

---

- TB_FieldRule //Table field rule

UUID_Rule,

Rule (numeric only, not null...)

---

- TB_UserTable //Save user designed thrir own table

UUID_Table,

Table_Name, (Designed table name)

---

- TB_UserTable_Field //Designed table field detail

UUID_TableField,

UUID_Table,

UUID_Type,

UUID_GroupID, (can be null if field is single type*)

UUID_Rule,

Field_Name, (Display name)

Field_Length,

---

- TB_Group //(for field(s) in multi type*, like RadioButton, DropwodnSelect... )

UUID,

GroupID,

GroupData,

Comment: Can i get the flow of the database. I am unable to understand this.

Comment: I can't upload any file due to some stupid office rule... you can create by yourself. Chcek out this SQLite Manager, it's quite easy~ https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Comment: BTW, you have another easy way to implement this, don't create any real table, just aassemble a "Create Table" sql script for your user.

Comment: So i have the file can i share it with you?

Comment: Sorry, my office blocked almost all online harddrive, even my private email...I'm not able to receive file now... :~(

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table for storing the field definitions with fields like this:

- survey_id (reference to the survey which the field belongs to)
- field_id (unique id of the field)
- field_type (checkbox, radio, plain etc.)
- field_label
- field_data (additional information if required, e.g. selection options for radio - dependent on type)
- field_index (defines the order of fields)
- ... any additional field you may need

From this data, you can dynamically build your GUI.

And you will need another table for storing the answers (if it is in scope of your app):

- field_id (reference to the former table)
- value (entered by the user)
- ...user_id, timestamp etc. according to your needs